# Android Studio - Move View (Linear Layout)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, move, ontouchlistener

it is almost 6 days traying to move the layout, but no success at all, trying alot of helps from internet but none helps..

[image]

I want llPic1 and llPic2 to be moved above ivNjeri with OnTouchListener.
So player to dicide which one need to be moved above ivNjeri.

With this code it vibrates on move and llPic1 and llPic2 goes under ivNjeri:

```
float dx = 0, dy = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            dx = x - view.getX();
            dy = y - view.getY();
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            view.setX(event.getX() - dx);
            view.setY(event.getY() - dy);
        }
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

I'm also trying alot of other codes but none works, any help will be very very appriciated :)

Comment: Are you trying to animate views this way ? Or whats your goal ?

Comment: yes, I want user to move view (LinearLayout or ImageView with OnTouchListener) above that big ImageView..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only 1 `ViewGroup` which holds all the images including an image to be overlapped and images to move.

**Why image cannot go over the big image?**

The small image on right side is inside of nested `LinearLayout` which is restricting the small image to be within the `LinearLayout`. That is why you can move the image inside of the child `LinearLayout` but not go beyond the boundary.

One example to fix it using `RelativeLayout` and fixed width on big image:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bigimage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/smallimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigimage"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bigimage"
        android:layout_below="@id/smallimage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to keep the precise weight, check out 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

This can give you weight control and can hold all views in 1 `ViewGroup`.

Comment: You saved my life it works, now can I make this small images fill the right screen (half screen first one half screen second one ) ?

Comment: `DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();             int height = display.heightPixels;
        int halfheight = height/2;
        ivSmallImage.getLayoutParams().height = halfheight;
        ivSmallImage.requestLayout();
It works for bigImage but not for this one

Comment: If you use PercentRelativeLayout, it would be very easy but if you don't want to use the dependency, you probably need to do math and use ViewTreeObserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying only to animate view why you dont use `Animation` for it like this:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);        
//  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)

animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
animation.setRepeatCount(1);  // animation repeat count
animation.setRepeatMode(1);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
//animation.setFillAfter(true);      

llPic1.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
```

Comment: this will move view by itselft, and again under that big view, like image 2

Comment: This will move your view by position you give it to constructor. And move linear layout holding your pic1 and pic2 in your component tree above ivNjeri a it should be okay

Answer (score 0):

you can try this tutorial [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html). i think you need remove your pic 1 or pic2 (if you want disapeare after dragging.) and then you should add another image view on ivNjeri view